# Php Redirect a page if chrome 18 is not found , without using javascript

Tags: php, redirect, external, server-side

I created this script a server side php code to redirect a page only if it finds the Chrome browser, but  this script does not work , how can I make sure to do the redirect of the url to a external page if chrome 18 has not been found ? I want to do the redirect to this website http://search.aol.com/aol/webhome

```html
<?php function is_chrome(
{
return(eregi("chrome/18", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])); }   if(is_chrome()) { header('Location: http://search.aol.com/aol/webhome'); } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is not correctly formatted, it should be `/chrome\/18/`.

Also, [`eregi`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) has been deprecated since php 5.3, so you shouldn't use this anymore. A better alternative would be [`preg_match`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
function is_chrome() {
    return preg_match("/chrome\/18/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) === 1; 
}
```

Comment: <?php function is_chrome() {
    return preg_match("/chrome\/18/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) === 1; 
}   if(is_chrome()) { header('Location: http://www.search.aol.com/aol/webhome'); } ?>